# Cannot run PlayWright inside docker image

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, playwright, playwright-sharp

I`m trying to create .net 5.0 docker image with playwright.
This is my DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Agent.csproj", "Agent/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Agent/Agent.csproj"
COPY . "/src/Agent"
WORKDIR "/src/Agent"
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
RUN npm install -g npm

RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Playwright
RUN dotnet build "Agent.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN npx playwright install
```

But once I run inside my image command `dotnet run Agent` it gives me following error:

```
Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-907428/chrome-linux/chrome
Please run the following command to download new browsers:              
║                                                                         
║     npx playwright install
```

Even though my dockerfile contains `RUN npx playwright install` seems like its not installing it. When I will remove it from my dockerfile and execute it manualy on running image it seems to be ok. Any ideas how I can execute properly playwright install using dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I have installed different version of chromium vs playwright

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a known issue in `Playwright`. You can see the detailed discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4033), and particularly see this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4033#issuecomment-855276404)

The solution I've seen mostly working is to either delete the `node_modules` entirely and then re-install it again, or in case of a docker image, try the solution mentioned in this [link](https://gkushang.medium.com/playwright-failed-to-launch-browsers-how-to-solve-8b01d03fe5b9), by setting the playwright browsers to a specific path

Comment: How can we set it to be a one-time installation within the docker image initialization part?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an environment variable: `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH="/ms-playwright"`
Hope to help you.