Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1117/chrome-linux/chrome
I am working on .NET 8.0 test project using C# with testing framework NUnit and Playwright.
I have written a Dockerfile as below
# Use an official .NET 8.0 SDK base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore NuGet packages
COPY *.sln ./
COPY EncryptionDecryptionUsingSymmetricKey/EncryptionDecryptionUsingSymmetricKey.csproj EncryptionDecryptionUsingSymmetricKey/
COPY MyTestProject/MyTestProject.csproj MyTestProject/
RUN dotnet restore

#Installing Playwright Separately
RUN rm -rf /root/.cache/ms-playwright
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y chromium
ENV CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install playwright
ENV CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1117/chrome-linux/chrome
RUN export PWADIR=/root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1117/chrome-linux/chrome
RUN echo "Chromium Executable Path: $CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH"  # Verify the Chromium executable path
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    fonts-liberation\
    libasound2\
    libatk-bridge2.0-0\
    libatk1.0-0\
    libatspi2.0-0\
    libcairo2\
    libcups2\
    libdbus-1-3\
    libdrm2\
    libgbm1\
    libglib2.0-0\
    libgtk-3-0\
    libnspr4\
    libnss3\
    libpango-1.0-0\
    libx11-6\
    libxcb1\
    libxcomposite1\
    libxdamage1\
    libxext6\
    libxfixes3\
    libxrandr2
    
# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Install NUnit and Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit NuGet packages
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package NUnit --version 3.14.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit --version 1.44.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration --version 8.0.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions --version 8.0.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json --version 8.0.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk --version 17.8.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package NUnit.Analyzers --version 3.9.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package NUnit3TestAdapter --version 4.5.0
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package Allure.NUnit --version 2.12.1
RUN dotnet add MyTestProject package coverlet.collector --version 6.0.0


# Build the application
RUN dotnet build


# Installing browser msedge
RUN dotnet tool update --global PowerShell
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y microsoft-edge-dev
#RUN echo $PATH | grep -q '/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-dev' || (echo "Error: Microsoft Edge not found in PATH" && exit 1)

 # Set the environment variable to point to the Microsoft Edge binary for Playwright
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-dev

#Installing Playwright using playwright.ps1
RUN pwsh /app/MyTestProject/bin/Debug/net8.0/playwright.ps1 install
RUN pwsh /app/MyTestProject/bin/Debug/net8.0/playwright.ps1 install-deps chromium

RUN dotnet publish MyTestProject/MyTestProject.csproj -c Release -o out

#Runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the built application from the build stage into this stage
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

# Execute the tests
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "MyTestProject.dll", "--settings:Runset.runsettings"]

In build I am installing Playwright and required browsers from section
#Installing Playwright using playwright.ps1
Before that also I am installing Playwright and browsers under section
#Installing Playwright Separately
Still I am facing issue that says
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
  Failed LogInInfo(MyTestProject.Assets.QA.TestsData.TestDataObj.Login) [649 ms]

Error Message:
   Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1117/chrome-linux/chrome
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright was just installed or updated.       ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers: ║
║                                                            ║
║     pwsh bin/Debug/netX/playwright.ps1 install             ║
║                                                            ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
  Stack Trace:
     at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.InnerSendMessageToServerAsync[T](ChannelOwner object, String method, Dictionary`2 dictionary, Boolean keepNulls) in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 206
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.WrapApiCallAsync[T](Func`1 action, Boolean isInternal) in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 532
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Core.BrowserType.LaunchAsync(BrowserTypeLaunchOptions options) in /_/src/Playwright/Core/BrowserType.cs:line 56
   at Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit.BrowserService.CreateBrowser(IBrowserType browserType) in /_/src/Playwright.NUnit/BrowserService.cs:line 55
   at Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit.BrowserService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Register>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Playwright.NUnit/BrowserService.cs:line 45
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit.WorkerAwareTest.RegisterService[T](String name, Func`1 factory) in /_/src/Playwright.NUnit/WorkerAwareTest.cs:line 55
   at Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit.BrowserTest.BrowserSetup() in /_/src/Playwright.NUnit/BrowserTest.cs:line 46
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.BlockUntilCompleted()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.MessagePumpStrategy.NoMessagePumpStrategy.WaitForCompletion(AwaitAdapter awaiter)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.SetUpTearDownItem.RunSetUpOrTearDownMethod(TestExecutionContext context, IMethodInfo method)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.SetUpTearDownItem.RunSetUp(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.SetUpTearDownCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.DelegatingTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)

Verified the respective path on image and haven't found any path root/.cache under it. Not sure what I'm missing

Could you please add logs from docker RUN pwsh /app/MyTestProject/bin/Debug/net8.0/playwright.ps1 install and install-deps chromium section? Also try insert additionally RUN pwsh /app/MyTestProject/bin/Debug/net8.0/playwright.ps1 install-deps (without chromium parameter) before line  with chromium parameter

Have you tried base image with PlayWright as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472876/cannot-run-playwright-inside-docker-image/78311480#78311480 ?

@MichaelFreidgeim, I tried, I think that should work but as I am a C# developer and new in Docker setup I am not sure how exactly I can use the base Image with playwright. If I use FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.40.0-jammy AS build-env it is not accepting dotnet Restore. Giving error: 0.211 /bin/sh: 1: dotnet: not found even after using RUN curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet --channel 8.0 command before dotnet restore

It seems that you inconsistent with manual
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-dev
And later
RUN pwsh /app/MyTestProject/bin/Debug/net8.0/playwright.ps1 install-deps chromium
Try to remove explicit ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH
And
ENV CHROMIUM_EXECUTABLE_PATH=

ohh, I added that before when I was trying to use edge browser. But missed to remove it later. Thanks for this quick catch. I will remove that and check for your other suggestions also.
